# Code executes, but not receiving mail in inbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

I have written code for sending email, and while the code executes successfully, the mail is not received in inbox. Please help me and correct the code; where is my mistake, or why is the mail not being received in inbox?

Here's my code, please tell me what the problem is.

I'm working on project in which forget password and username send to user who enter email ID.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string email = TextBox1.Text;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=regester;Integrated Security=True");
        string command = "select id,password,email from reg ";

        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);
        //sqlcmd.Parameters["@Email"].Value = email;
        //sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", email);
        con.Open();

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            SqlDataReader dtr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dtr.Read())
            {
                if (dtr[2].ToString().Equals(TextBox1.Text))
                {
                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    mail.To.Add(dtr[2].ToString());
                    mail.From = new MailAddress("mian722@hotmail.com");
                    mail.Subject = "Your userId and Password";
                    mail.Body = "Your<br/> UserId:<b>" + dtr[0].ToString() + "</b><br/>" + "Password:<b>" + dtr[1].ToString() + "</b>";
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    smtp.Port = 587;

                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your id", "your password");
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    //smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    //smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    //smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true; //Gmail works on Server Secured Layer
                    try
                    {
                        smtp.Send(mail);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }  
                    //smtp.Send(mail);

                    Label1.Text = "check your mailbox for user iD and Password";

                    string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n" + "alert('User Id and password send to Your mail box');\n" + "</script>";
                    RegisterStartupScript("xyz", javaScript);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Email Id not valid";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see if this helps: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/csharp.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

string email = TextBox1.Text;
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["regesterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=regester;Integrated Security=True");
            string command = "select uname,password,email from reg ";
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);
            //sqlcmd.Parameters["@Email"].Value = email;
            //sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", email);
            con.Open();
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                SqlDataReader dtr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

```
            while (dtr.Read())
            {
                if (dtr[2].ToString().Equals(TextBox1.Text))
                {



                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    mail.To.Add(dtr[2].ToString());
                    mail.From = new MailAddress("youremail@hotmail.com");
                    mail.Subject = "Your userId and Password";
                    mail.Body = "Your<br/> UserId:<b>" + dtr[0].ToString() + "</b><br/>" + "Password:<b>" + dtr[1].ToString() + "</b>";

                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com";


                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yyyyyyyy@hotmail.com", "xxxxxx");
                    // NetworkCredential.UserName = "";
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Port = 25;

                    //TLS / SSL required = yes;
                    //smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    //smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    //smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    //smtp.EnableSsl = true; //Gmail works on Server Secured Layer
                    //try
                    //{
                    //    smtp.Send(mail);
                    //}
                    //catch (Exception ex)
                    //{}
                     smtp.Send(mail);









                    Label1.Text = "check your mailbox for user iD and Password";

                    string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n" + "alert('User Id and password send to Your mail box');\n" + "</script>";
                    RegisterStartupScript("xyz", javaScript);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Email Id not valid";
                }

            }
```

Comment: are you using the correct credentials for your email from which you send the mail ? Tell us what if there is an exception thrown when you do smtp.Send(mail).

Answer (score 1):

This line discard any exceptions that are throw by `Send`. Remove the try and catch, put some kind of logging or even just put a break point on it. Then, hopefully, you can tell us what the exception was.

```
try
{
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Comment: For sure this is the **catch all - see nothing** trap :o)

Comment: if i remove this then smtp.send(mail ) create error  

try
{
    smtp.Send(mail);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}

Comment: @TousifIrshad Good, I should hope so. What is the error?

Comment: brother i change services and now working with hotmail so code is runing corectly

Answer (score 0):

You may want to be more specific in your error handling, at least until you find the problem

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    string email = TextBox1.Text;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=regester;Integrated Security=True");
    string command = "select id,password,email from reg ";

    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);
    //sqlcmd.Parameters["@Email"].Value = email;
    //sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", email);
    con.Open();

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        SqlDataReader dtr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dtr.Read())
        {
            if (dtr[2].ToString().Equals(TextBox1.Text))
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add(dtr[2].ToString());
                mail.From = new MailAddress("mian722@hotmail.com");
                mail.Subject = "Your userId and Password";
                mail.Body = "Your<br/> UserId:<b>" + dtr[0].ToString() + "</b><br/>" + "Password:<b>" + dtr[1].ToString() + "</b>";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;

                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your id", "your password");
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                //smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                //smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                //smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true; //Gmail works on Server Secured Layer
                try
                {
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
                catch (SmtpException ex)
                {
                    string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n" + "alert('SMTP mail exception: " + Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HTMLEncode(ex.Message) + "');\n" + "</script>";
                    RegisterStartupScript("xyz", javaScript);
                    // add logging here
                    break;
                }  
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n" + "alert('A general exception sending mail: " + Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HTMLEncode(ex.Message) + "');\n" + "</script>";
                    RegisterStartupScript("xyz", javaScript);
                    // add logging here
                    break;
                }  

                Label1.Text = "check your mailbox for user iD and Password";

                string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n" + "alert('User Id and password send to Your mail box');\n" + "</script>";
                RegisterStartupScript("xyz", javaScript);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Email Id not valid";
            }
        }
      }
    }
  } catch(SqlException sqlexcept)
    {
         string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n" + "alert('SQL exception: '" + Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HTMLEncode(sqlexcept.Message) ");\n" + "</script>";
          RegisterStartupScript("xyz", javaScript);
          // add logging here
    }
  } catch(Exception except)
    {
         string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n" + "alert('General mail creation exception: '" + Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HTMLEncode(except.Message) ");\n" + "</script>";
          RegisterStartupScript("xyz", javaScript);
          // add logging here
    }
}
```

web.config settings for mail.

```
    <system.net> 
     <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="myname@outlook.com">
        <network host="smtp-mail.outlook.com" userName="myname@outlook.com" password="<passwordhere>" port="587" enableSsl="true"/>
      </smtp>
     </mailSettings>
   </system.net>
```

Comment: same problem occur not receiving mail inbox

Comment: Then the problem is not in the code itself, it is most likely in your web.config file. I updated my answer to show the smtp settings for outlook/hotmail